# Find the busiest hour for each stackexchange site

Tags: code-golf, internet, stack-exchange-api

**Input**

Name of a [stackexchange site](https://stackexchange.com/sites) or any way to uniquely identify the site.

**Output** The hour of the day that had the largest number of answers posted over the previous 24 hours. E.g. 14:00-15:00 GMT.

You can take the input and give output in any easily human readable format.

Your code can access the Internet but only the site's API. Previous 24 hours should be from the start of the current hour.

Out of politeness, please don't test your code on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) where the number of queries may need to be high.

Comment: Is the input the API name of the site? e.g. `webapps.meta` for Web Applications Meta

Comment: @Arnauld Good point. Yes.

Comment: We can access the web, right? But only the site's API, correct? You may want to mention that in the challenge. Also, does "previous 30 days" mean with respect to today (June 17, 2020) or to the time when the program is run?

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks. Question amended.

Comment: Great, upvoted!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the API, so I may be wrong. But it seems like we need to retrieve _all_ answers posted during 30 days in order to extract the relevant timestamp and build the hourly stats. For Stack Overflow, that's ~6800 answers per day and ~200K answers for 30 days. The maximum number of results per request is 100, so that's ~2000 calls to the API, which I think is unreasonable for a recreational challenge.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic due to asking for malicious code. Cf. https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4829/43319

Comment: @Adám I amended the question. Hopefully OK now (I clearly don't want malicious code!)

Comment: @Arnauld Question amended. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Anush I don't think so. Per Arnauld's numbers, that'd still be up to 70 calls to the API *per solution*, not to mention the testing phase when developing one's solution.

Comment: Let's discuss in chat.

Comment: @Arnauld Isn't the simple solution to not run the code on SO?

Comment: @user202729 yes. I will edit to say that.

Comment: @user202729 I don't know for sure. I suspect that the number of API calls will still be pretty high for many other sites.

Comment: @Arnauld  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LCr0.png suggests the difference is really huge so the number of queries needed for any other site will be pretty limited.

Comment: @Adám Could you explain how this is or was asking for malicious code?

Comment: @pppery It was asking to hammer SE with API requests.

Comment: This is very sad :(  It definitely looks like a programming challenge/code-golf question to me.